# How to achieve a layout like this?

Tags: tikz-pgf, footnotes, boxes, arrows

This is an example from the Essay "Host" by David Foster Wallace (as published in "Consider the Lobster").

What would it look like to recreate this in LaTeX?

Could there be an (semi)automatic solution, e.g. for converting footnotes into these arrows+textboxes?

[image: host example 1]

[image: host example 2]

[image: host example 3]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That looks ... confusing. But I like the question (+1).

Comment: You realize that the placement of the boxes is nearly random?  This is more of an artistic statement.

Comment: Just some random ideas you could work on: define your own command, `\notetextbox{<width>}{<text>}`, which inserts a tikz-node, an environment (probably using something like wrapfigure containing a huge TikZ node with the border and the text), and then draws a link between them. However, I have no idea yet how to draw the arrows, especially with the pagebreaks.